# Google test problem with including gtest.h because of other h file in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

Long story short i have Tests, that i want to run with GoogleTest. I cloned git repo with GoogleTest,tried to include gtest.h, but it can't see it. I also tried to type path by myself and it helped.. kinda. Now there is error in gtest.h itself and gives me error that says "cannot open source file "gtest/gtest-assertion-result.h" (dependency of "*path to repo*\lib\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\gtest.h")". Send help!

[structure of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdA9O.png)

Also that is my include -
`#include "../lib/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h"`

Tried recloning and reloading only

Comment: If you cannot find the `gtest.h` header, then you have to add it as an include directory, which is done differently depending on build system, but is documented for Bazel and CMake in their [documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)

Comment: *"`#include "../lib/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h`"*, You generally add the path in include pathes to only have `#include <gtest/gtest.h>`...

Comment: @Jarod42 <gtest/gtest.h> can't even find gtest.h for some reason

Comment: Show your compilation command line...

Comment: @Jarod42 https://imgur.com/a/G0OHDlU

Comment: It should be `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` with `-I../lib/googletest/googletest/include/` in your compilation command. No wonder gtest internals cannot find correct file if it's not on the include search path.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen as i said, i tried and that's the result: https://imgur.com/a/LaERWYC

Comment: @ВіталікГук As I said, you have to add include directory to your compilation command with `-I` option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen how i can add include  directort to my comilation command